# Wordpress can't see symlinked theme in Ubuntu

Tags: themes, apache

I know there are security issues with symlinks but this is for development purposes on my local machine only.

I am trying to set up my wordpress development server. My workflow results in a 'build' directory with the wordpress theme and I want to symlink that directory to my wordpress installation (which uses a non-standard port).

```
ln -s ~/code/Dropbox/HTML/af2015/build/ /home/[...]/public_html/[...]/wp-content/themes/af2015

lrwxrwxrwx 1 [..] [..]      42 Apr  4 09:43 af2015 -> /home/[..]/code/Dropbox/HTML/af2015/build
```

I've read all the instructions and added the `FollowSymLinks` command (see below), but Wordpress still cannot see my theme. Can anyone help?

```
<VirtualHost *:61112>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@amsterdamfoodie.nl
  DocumentRoot /home/simon/public_html

  <Directory /home/simon/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    # Order allow,deny
    # allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 61112
```

Comment: I just ran into this myself. In my case I had to add execute permissions to my home directory so the server could get to the symlinked folder (`chmod o+x $HOME`). More [here](http://serverfault.com/a/450587).

Comment: Thanks. this was indeed the problem. But i just could not work out how far down the diretory tree i had to go to chmod, so i moved the directory in question....